# Saving state for presentModalViewController in iOS application

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiviewcontroller

I am creating a application where I require a filter button. When I click on filter button, ModalViewController will pop from the bottom of the screen.

```
    [self presentModalViewController:filterActivity animated:YES];
```

When I am done with that filter screen I am dismissing it with

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Now problem is when I dismissModalViewController then all the date entered in UITextField is gone. Is there any way to save the data or save the state of presentModalViewController ?

Comment: Is the textField in the modalVC or the mainVC ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve the problem. By using Singleton pattern I have solve the problem. Now I can see data in text filed or label even if i dismiss the modalviewcontroller and come back again. Code for Singleton

```
+ (MNActivityFilter *) sharedManager {
static dispatch_once_t once;
static MNActivityFilter *sharedManager;
dispatch_once(&once, ^ { sharedManager = [[MNActivityFilter alloc] init]; });
return sharedManager;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

A standard way to accomplish this is to create a protocol that has say a method "- (void)userUpdates:(NSDIctionary *)dict", and have the master view controller implement it. Give the modal view controller a "@property (non atomic, weak) id  delegate" property, and set it before running the modal object. Then, if the user does update some info, provide it back to the master controller using the protocol.